# Cannot import name 'hdrs'

Tags: python, discord

I'm coding a discord bot right now. The code was literally working yesterday and I didn't change anything but now I'm getting this import error. I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Pycharm and the most recent version of Discord.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yishi/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\yishi\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\yishi\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\yishi\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import hdrs as hdrs
ImportError: cannot import name 'hdrs'
```

Comment: If the code was working yesterday could it be that now youre using different python interpreter to run the code?

Comment: I restarted the project and everything seems to work. I suspect I might have accidentally installed a package with a similar name as a discord dependency from the requirements.txt file I made for heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to a recent version of Python like 3.8 or 3.9

Comment: The problem is not probably dependent on the Python version, since it had worked with Python 3.6 previously.